# If matrix $A$ is similar to $B$ (say, $A=(P^{-1})BP$ ), prove that:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> If matrix $A$ is similar to $B$ (say, $A=P^{-1}BP$ ), prove that:
>
> 1. $A$ is similar to $A$
> 2. If $A$ is similar to $B$, then $B$ is similar to $A$
> 3. If $A$ is similar to $B$ and $B$ is similar to $C$, then $A$ is similar to $C$.

I got an answer for $1$ as $A=(I^{-1})AI$, I assume this is correct

Could someone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

$$A=P^{-1}BP\implies B=PAP^{-1}\;,\;\;$$

and also

$$A=P^{-1}BP\;,\;\;B=Q^{-1}CQ\implies A=P^{-1}Q^{-1}CQP=\ldots$$

Comment: what do you mean by Q?

Comment: @i.ru An invertible matrix as assured by similarity, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A$ is similar to $B$. Then

$A = P^{-1}BP$

Multiplying both sides by $P$ to the left, we obtain

$PA= P P^{-1}BP = BP$

Multiplying both side by $P^{-1}$ to the right, we get

$PAP^{-1} = BPP^{-1} = B$.

Therefore, $B$ is similar to $A$.

Comment: For part (3), note that $(PQ)^{-1}=Q^{-1}P^{-1}$, and substituting to get the desired result, I hope that it is useful for you.

Comment: For part (1), you are right since the inverse matrix of Identity matrix is itself.